# MS Word is numbering the pages wrong starting at 2

Tags: microsoft-word

strong textMy MS Word document starts to number the pages at 2 instead of 1.

I have tried to go into the Format Page Numbers... property and set it to Start at 1. It remained at 2. I also tried continue form previous section and it still remained at 2.

I have tried simply updating the field and nothing happened.

I then investigated if the document contains sections (pagebreaks) that I was not seeing by using the `{PAGE}` command. I inserted it directly in front of the first line in the header and it still returned 2.

I have also looked at the field code for the page number and it looks correct with just PAGE as the command.

**How can I get my word document to start numbering my pages correctly?**

I suspect that a non existent coversheet might be at fault. Can't figure out how to check for this though.

Any suggestions for debugging welcome!

Comment: Do you have this issue with only one document, or multiple? Have you tried copying the whole document to a new one?

Comment: I have created a new document with no content and didn't have the issue there. Just tried copying the document and infact I couldn't enter any new page numbers.

Comment: When I delete the page number field and manually reinsert it using F9, I can adjust the page number to start either at 0 or at 2, but not at 1!

Comment: Maybe you have a section break forcing your page to start on even page?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Select the first character in your document, press CTRL+SHIFT+HOME, than delete.

Comment: Tried it and the page number remains at 2. I looked into the original document again and saw that the Field Code was `PAGE  \2 `... I have deleted this to simply read `PAGE` but it had no effect. Perhaps this setting has some impact that I am not aware of?

Comment: Is it possible for you to prepare a test document with this issue? For example you could leave only the first page, then check if the issue exists, then keep removing text/objects from the first page until the issue disappears or the document is empty. Then you could upload this empty doc for easier investigation.

Comment: I don't use Word, but it sounds like your page format is defined as an even-numbered page. It's the sort of thing books use to make even and odd pages have different margins, headers, and footers.

Comment: @Joe That was in fact the answer to the question! Thanks. The document was set to start on an even page number. If you post this as the answer I can award it to you!